# Querydsl - How to get sum of columns

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl

These below is my STOCK TABLE info

```
id, bigint(20)
available_quantity, int(11)
allocation_quantity, int(11)
stop_quantity, int(11)
damage_quantity, int(11)
standby_quantity, int(11)
```

I'd like to do a query than in sql it's:

```sql
SELECT 
 available_quantity,
 allocation_quantity,
 stop_quantity,
 damage_quantity,
 standby_quantity,
 available_quantity + allocation_quantity + standby_quantity
FROM STOCK
```

I tried searching for the solution, but the closest I get was:

```java
     return queryFactory
                .select(new QStockResponseDto(
                        stock.availableQuantity,
                        stock.standbyQuantity,
                        stock.allocationQuantity,
                        stock.availableQuantity + stock.standbyQuantity + stock.allocationQuantity 
                )).from(stock)
```

but this indicates below error

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.NumberPath<java.lang.Integer>', 'com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.NumberPath<java.lang.Integer>'
```

i don't know how to get this 'available_quantity + allocation_quantity + standby_quantity' in QueryDSL:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message gives you a great hint about the issue.  The value stock.availableQuantity, stock.standbyQuantity, and stock.allocationQuantity are all objects of type NumberExpression.  Read the NumberExpression documentation here:

https://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/NumberExpression.html

I do not have QueryDSL set up local at this time to validate this, but I think you simply need to replace:

```
stock.availableQuantity + stock.standbyQuantity + stock.allocationQuantity
```

with this:

```
stock.availableQuantity.add(stock.standbyQuantity).add(stock.allocationQuantity)
```

If you need to provide an alias for that result, append the .as(Path<>) method after the second add() method.  Let us know if this works.